# ISDN: Usb Modem Windows XP

Tags: networking, windows-xp, usb, modem

So I have a D-LINK Windows XP ISDN Modem which I have to use to contact our telephone service in the building. I'd love it to run under Windows 7 or 8 but it doesn't.

However the USB-modem is installed correctly (the light is green) and it's visible in "Computer > Manage" it does not receive any ISDN connection.

The line is working, as I can perform phone calls through it when I connect a (Siemens) telephone.
How can I get this ISDN line working? [image: Information Kiosk]

Comment: Can you run the app in XP compatibility mode and see if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

ISDN is a three layer protocol. First there is a *pyhsical level* (layer one) ,then *LAP-D* (layer two)and then *Q.930* (layer 3).

The Siemens phone is compatible in all the three layers with the telco provider since is able to generate calls.

Have you checked that the *D-LINK Windows XP ISDN Modem* (features & configuration) is fully compatible (all the three layers) with the telco provider?

It seems as there is difference of features at layers 2 or 3. Check what is the exact meaning of the green light on the modem.